# Most practical and efficient way to filter objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, filtering, django-queryset

What is the best approach to filter objects in `Django`?

In my case, I need to filter objects by different params sent by `GET request`. So, in my `get_queryset` of `CBV` I send the values to the custom function of my custom `models.QuerySet` and retrieve the result:

```
return MyModel.objects.all().custom_filter(param1, param2, param3)
```

But in my custom function, the most doubtful things happening.

1. At first, I check passed values for existence and clean them.
2. Then, separately for every param I filter queryset using `Q Objects`. In custom `models.QuerySet` it looks like:

   ```
   def custom_filter(self, param1, param2, param3):
       # cleaning and checking staff
       # ... then
       result = self.filter(Q() | Q()) # related to param1
       if (param2 != None):
           result = result.filter(Q()) # related to param2
       if (param3 != None):
           result = result.filter(Q() & Q()) # related to param3
       # and etc.
       return result.distinct()
   ```

This works fine for that time. But I think it is definitely **inefficient**. If anyone has a better solution, please provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think - measure. How long does it take to do the query? Can you test it in a production style region *before* deploying it?

You can view the query that is sent to the database by looking at `.query` on any queryset. By seeing the real query in this way you will have a much better idea as to whether your query is horrible.

```
print unicode(MyModel.objects.all().custom_filter(param1, param2, param3).query)
```

If you want a more advanced breakdown, usually I take these and pop it into an `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on the database. That will give you a full breakdown on what magic your database is using to actually collect your results. You'll need to look up your database documentation for more information on this method as it varies though.

Lastly - but perhaps most importantly - [querysets only evaluate when they have to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). In the example you provided, no database queries will be made at all. You think it is definitely inefficient - but I can't see any reason as to why you would think that.

Comment: I'm a quite a new in Django. I really didn't know that `QuerySet`s are lazy.

Comment: It makes a huge difference :)